# why browsers add http:// and domain name in front of url when using proxy

Tags: http, browser, proxy

when requesting firefox to open example.com it sends:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
...
```

but when using proxy, firefox sends:

```
GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
...
```

I checked a few other browsers and they behave the same.

I examined some http proxy software such as squid and saw that they remove

```
http://example.com
```

from url and send something like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
...
```

What is the reason and is this a standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is needed to identify the protocol the proxy must use to query the end server.

This is specified in the RFC 2616: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1.2